# A naïve question about transition map and contravariant vectors

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to check something with you.

We have a manifold $M$ and a point $p$ that belongs to $M$. I consider two charts $(U,\phi_U)$ and $(V,\phi_V)$ where $p \in U \cap V$. For simplicity of notations, I call $x=\phi_U$ and $y=\phi_V$ the coordinates.

If I am interested on coordinates of points in $U \cap V$, I could either describe it by using $x$ or $y$ and the transition map between $U$ and $V$ would be the function $\phi_V \circ \phi_U^{-1}$ **that is very general and not necesseraly linear**.

Now, I am interested in describing vectors in $T_pM$. Again I could use $x$ or $y$ coordinates to write them. **But** the map that express a change of coordinates will be a **linear map**. More precisely I'll have : $v_{x'}=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}v_x+\frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}v_y$

But imagine I work in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I take the vector $\vec{v}=3\vec{U_x}+2\vec{U_y}$. I imagine a change of coordinates : $x'=x^2,y'=3y$. In the new basis, the vector is now : $\vec{v}=9\vec{U_x'}+6\vec{U_y'}$

And I don't have : $v_{x'}=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}v_x+\frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}v_y$. Indeed, if I use this equation I would end up with :
$v_{x'}=(2*3)*3+(0)*2=18$.

**I know how to derive the equation expressing a change of base for the vectors in a manifold by using the action of a vector of a function**, what I want to be sure of the reason what I say is wrong.

I think it is because in my example of vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ my "transition map" was a transition map directly defined on the tangent space. So it was not $\phi_V \circ \phi_U^{-1}$ I used but another type of transition map defined on tangent space. Do you agree with me ?

But in fact if I use a linear change of coordinates for the vectors the formula works so maybe I am not allowed to do a change of basis not linear in tangent spaces. But why ???!

I insist I don't want a proof of the formula of change of basis of vectors linked to change of coordinates of charts but I want to really understand why my example doesn't work to better understand the global structure around manifolds.

Comment: What is that new basis which allows you to write the new coordinates ?

Comment: @TsemoAristide I am not sure to understand your question but the new basis is $x'=x^2$ and $y'=3y$.

Comment: You, in fact, *don't* have $v_{x'}=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}v_x+\frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}v_y$. It looks like you're mixing up the formulas for relating differentials and for relating tangent vectors.

Comment: You say the coordinates in the new basis is $9U'_x+6U'_y$ what is that new basis ? It seems you have two candidates for the answer, because you says it is not the answer I expect.

Comment: @Hurkyl I edited, it doesn't exist in english :D. I wanted to say expressing. (I am thinking about all the comment I answer to the other question in few minutes)

Comment: @Hurkyl but isn't the expression for a push-forward (differential) and a change of basis the same ? Can't we say that a change of basis is a particular case of push-forward ?

Comment: @TsemoAristide what I mean is that as $x'=x^2$, if my vector was 2 length long in $\vec{U_x}$ it would be 4 length long in the new base $\vec{U_{x'}}$. But if I use the formulas of a change of basis for vector, ie $v_{x'}=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}v_x+\frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}v_y$ I don't end up with the same result which is my confusion. I don't know if that was your question ? I probably misunderstand what you are asking